# RecyclerView: fill screen heigth when AppBarLayout scrolls up (hides)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-appbarlayout

I have AppBarLayout with toolbar and 2 buttons. It hides when I scroll RecyclerView up and shows when I scroll down.
The problem is that RecyclerView is set to be below AppBarLayout and preserves its position when AppBarLayout hides and I have condition shown on the picture. I need my RecyclerView to scroll up to the statusbar as well, and return to original position on scroll down. So far I could not even find an example of that.
Thank you.
[image]

This is mt layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ru.skyeng.listening.AudioFiles.AudioListActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
 >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gear"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_category"
            android:layout_width="158dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_category"
            android:text="@string/categories"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_length"
            android:layout_width="158dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_button_length"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/length"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue2"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/shadow"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_length"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow">
        </View>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp">
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show us your XML ?

Comment: you need to use a CoordinatorLayout  --  CollapsingToolbarLayout -- check under 9 here on how to do it http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: @Tasso, this definitely helped. If you write some explanation here for others, I will mark your answer as accepted one. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image to show on bellow the toolbar. You should try CollpsingLayoutToolbar.

Here is an example. I hope this helps

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|right"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBarStyle"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        app:title="@string/pod">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_ImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: No, I need my recyclerView to move up as my toolbar (AppBarLayout) hides.

Comment: You can add the RecyclerView bellow the Collapsing toolbar  and  when you scroll the whole toolbar will collapse until only the RecyclerView  is visible

Comment: Thats right, but recyclerview should not go under AppBarLayout, it should move along with it.  
@Tasso gave very useful link that helped me to achieve this. Anyway, thank you for suggestion.